# Sorting 2D list of strings

Tags: c#

I have a 2D list of strings (List of Lists of strings). I want to sort it based on some particular column.

```
List<List<String>> matrix = new List<List<String>>();
matrix.Add(new List<String>());
matrix[0].Add("A"); 
matrix[0].Add("1"); 
matrix[0].Add("2");       

matrix.Add(new List<String>());
matrix[1].Add("B"); 
matrix[1].Add("0"); 
matrix[1].Add("1");           

matrix.Add(new List<String>());
matrix[2].Add("C"); 
matrix[2].Add("0"); 
matrix[2].Add("2");

matrix.Add(new List<String>());
matrix[3].Add("D"); 
matrix[3].Add("1"); 
matrix[3].Add("1");
```

When it is sorted based on column 2 it should look like this:

```
Column 1        Column 2        Column 3
--------        --------        --------
B               0               1
C               0               2
A               1               2
D               1               1
```

When it is sorted based on column 3 it should look like this:

```
Column 1        Column 2        Column 3
--------        --------        --------
B               0               1
D               1               1
A               1               2
C               0               2
```

Sorting of a secondary column is appreciated but not necessary (when column 2 is primary column 3 is secondary and vice versa). In my examples, secondary columns are not sorted.

Comment: are the index numbers you use with matrix correct ?

Comment: @Shekhar: I guess not indeed. That seems a typo... Fixed.

Comment: There isn't much detail to go on, but it looks as though the second list level would be better off implemented as either a class or Tuple

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var orderedResult = matrix.OrderBy(x => x[1])
```

Where `1` is the index of the second item in the list. I would suggest though not to create a list of lists, but a 2D array, or a 1D array with an appropriate type.

This is very unsafe, in particular when you have lists of varying sizes. You could 'improve' this using a length check:

```
var orderedResult = matrix.OrderBy(x => x.Count > 1 ? x[1] : null)
```

If you want the result as a `List`, use `ToList()`:

```
var orderedResult = matrix.OrderBy(x => x.Count > 1 ? x[1] : null).ToList()
```

Comment: I don't know why but it didn't work. If I use 2D array then how can I write the code?

Comment: I used two columns. One for the name and the other for the value. They just switched position. I mean the value became first column and the name became second.